# Как настроить отправку почты с вложением, где имя у вложения всегда меняется?

Tags: bash

Подскажите, как реализовать.

Есть скрипт, который отправляет сообщение с вложением

```
#!/bin/bash
for I in `cat list_adresses`; do cat body | mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" -a 
"/path/to/directory/File_name_29.04.21" -s "Тема письма" -- $I < body;echo $I;sleep 1 ;done
```

Вся штука в том, что имя файла всегда меняется, а именно меняется дата в имени файла. Сегодня _29.04.21, завтра _30.04.21.

Как настроить вложение, чтобы скрипт делал вложения исходя из первой части имени файла -- File_name

Answer (score 0):

Вообще все очень просто

делаем переменную

```
attach=$(ls /path/to/file/ | grep File_name)
```

И вкладываем переменную во вложение

```
-a  "/path/to/directory/$attach"
```

Comment: А если старые файлы там же хранятся? Попробуйте, очень интересные результаты будут у вашей команды.